# Strsplit function in R

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I'm currently working through some coursework where data has been provided on supermarket chip sales. Part of the task is to remove any entries where products are not chips and have been provided code to enter to help with this:

```r
productWords <- data.table(unlist(strsplit(unique(transaction_data[, "PROD_NAME"]), "")))
```

the data file provided = transaction_data and PROD_NAME variable is the column we're interested in.

This however, returns the error:

```
Error in strsplit(unique(transaction_data[, "PROD_NAME"]), "") : non-character argument
```

Can someone please explain what it is that I'm doing wrong, or am I missing something? I'm not sure how this code would be able to understand the product and differentiate between another, am I meant to be adding something in with the code based on product names I've seen while looking through the data?

Here are some lines of the data as an example:

```
  DATE       STORE_NBR LYLTY_CARD_NBR TXN_ID PROD_NBR PROD_NAME                                PROD_QTY TOT_SALES
  <date>         <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                                       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2018-10-17         1           1000      1        5 Natural Chip        Compny SeaSalt175g          2       6  
2 2019-05-14         1           1307    348       66 CCs Nacho Cheese    175g                        3       6.3
3 2019-05-20         1           1343    383       61 Smiths Crinkle Cut  Chips Chicken 170g          2       2.9
```

Comment: You need `[[` instead of `[` i.e. `transaction_data[["PROD_NAME"]]` as it is a tibble

Comment: For explanation: `data.frame` (base), `tbl_df` (dplyr dialect, what you have here), and `data.table` all behave slightly differently for single-column selection. Base R automatically "reduces" the dimensionality to a vector when the result is just one column, see `mtcars[,2]`, whereas 2 or more will return a frame (`mtcars[,2:3]`). Both `tbl_df` and `data.table` will always return a frame, even when just one column, see `tibble(mtcars)[,2]`; this is considered a "safety feature", and base R's behavior sometimes seen as undesired. There are ways around it, none "awesome" in my book.

Comment: You might not need to `strsplit(`, per se, though all the above are valid points. Perhaps, `grepl('Chip | Chips', c('Natural Chip Company Seasalt', 'CCs Nacho Cheese', 'Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips')
+ )
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE` where `grepl` replaces your `strsplit`, with `[[`approach gets you to chips, but note domain knowledge required to clarify CCs Nacho.